# Mounting available drive through autofs

Tags: linux, mount, cache, freeipa

We manage a lot of workstations on CentOS 7.4 with different hardware configurations.
They all share an automount map managed by FreeIPA.

On those workstations, we mount a cache disk on `/path/to/cache/`.
In the automount map, so far, we've always used the `sdb1` key for this mount point:

`/path/to/cache -fstype=ext4 :/dev/sdb1`

On some new workstations, we now have nvme disk for caching. So of course, the path is different `/dev/nvme0n1`.

We would like to handle those two cases. 
Is there a way to set this up in freeipa or more basically in a single autofs command?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to you to use partition labeling since ext4 filesystems can handle it :

1- Relabel all the partitions on the workstations with a common label :

```
e2label <partition_name> <partition_label>
```

2- Edit your autofs line :

```
/path/to/cache -fstype=ext4 :LABEL=<partition_label>
```